# How to update react swiper when orientation change?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swiper.js

When i change orientation on tablet the slider breaks (shows 1 broken slide). Expected behavior ( 2 slides 50% width in portrait orientation). I try to fix with ref.current.swiper.update(), but it don't work

```
const ref = useRef()
const handleResize = () => {
  ref?.current.swiper.update()
}

useEventListener('resize', handleResize)

<Swiper
  loop
  watchOverflow
  ref={ref}
  className="apartment-swiper"
  breakpoints={{
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
    },
    1280: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
    },
  }}
>
  {photo?.map((item, index) => (
    <SwiperSlide className="swiper-slide" key={index}>
      <img className="swiper-slide" src={item.url} alt="slide" />
    </SwiperSlide>
  ))}
</Swiper>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the [parameters](https://swiperjs.com/api/#parameters) `updateOnWindowResize` or `observer` properties

```
<Swiper
 loop
 watchOverflow
 observer={'true'}
 className="apartment-swiper"
 breakpoints={{
   768: {
     slidesPerView: 'auto',
   },
   1280: {
     slidesPerView: 1,
   },
 }}
>
 {photo?.map((item, index) => (
   <SwiperSlide className="swiper-slide" key={index}>
     <img className="swiper-slide" src={item.url} alt="slide" />
   </SwiperSlide>
 ))}
</Swiper>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem -  `swiperRef1.current.swiper.autoplay.timeout` = 366 by def!:)
To do:

```
console.log(swiperRef1.current.swiper)
        swiperRef1.current.swiper.autoplay.timeout = 3;
        console.log(swiperRef1.current.swiper.autoplay.timeout)
```